# Spawn a custom horse with a custom rider

Tags: java, bukkit

I would like to spawn a custom horse and its custom rider mob, and then customize them both. As soon as you call `spawn(loc, Horse.class)`, though, you can't call `getEntity()` it anymore before it spawned.
Neither can you spawn a mob from a variable like `spawn(loc, custommob);` or any pre-customized entity. And you cannot instantiate a `new Horse();`.

So the horse needs to be spawned without any customization, without rider, before it can be modified. But that will trigger an `EntitySpawnEvent` which will be cancelled because 'default horses' are not allowed in my world to spawn. And there is no customization I can give it to later recognize it and so to make it pass that cancel.

Same problem I have with its rider, I can't customize it in anyway before it spawned and I can't recognize it as the rider after it spawned because of that.
If I spawn anything that is on the spawn blacklist it will just be cancelled and if I spawn anything on the whitelist it will just spawn and be unidentifiable. I don't want any random mob existing to suddenly be the rider.

How can I spawn these two mobs, customize them, and make them find each other and passenger each other while respecting the blacklist?

```
@EventHandler
public void onMobSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {
    String world = event.getEntity().getWorld().getName();
    if (world.equals("Someworld") || world.equals("Someotherworld")) {
        if (event.getEntityType().equals(EntityType.SKELETON)) { // Whitelisted
            // Continue whitelist actions
        }
    } else {
        /* I could add here to spawn the horse, and add an exception to the filter.
         * But how do I customize it?
         * I can't customize it before it spawned and I can't get it after it spawned.
         * Same for the rider.
         */
        // loc.getWorld().spawn(loc, Horse.class);
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CreatureSpawnEvent.getSpawnReason()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/CreatureSpawnEvent.html#getSpawnReason()) is a good workaround to your problem.
Look at [`SpawnReason.CUSTOM`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/CreatureSpawnEvent.SpawnReason.html#CUSTOM).

> When a creature is spawned by plugins

```
@EventHandler
public void onNormal(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {
    // This will prevent an infinite loop
    if (event.getSpawnReason() != SpawnReason.CUSTOM) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        // Spawn what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with their custom name and even their armor but none worked. I added this exact method and it still does the same crash though.

Comment: @Myst [I explained you why it crashes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264964/spawn-a-custom-horse-with-a-custom-rider#comment44912575_28265842) Reset your project: let my code handle the `CreatureSpawnEvent` event, then spawn the horse with its passenger.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is possible to get the horse after it spawns. When calling `world.spawnEntity(Location, EntityType)`, it returns the entity spawned.

So, to get a horse once it spawns, you could use:

```
Entity entity = location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.HORSE);
Horse horse = (Horse) entity
```

Once you have the horse, you can customize it in any way you like, such as:

```
horse.setCustomName("My Custom Horse");
```

Or

```
horse.setPassenger(horseRider);
```

You can also do this for any other entity you like. So, here's what your code could look like:

```
Horse horse = (Horse) location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.HORSE);
Skeleton rider = (Skeleton) location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.SKELETON);
//customize the rider and horse in any way you want

horse.setPassenger(rider);
```

If you're going to be calling this code within a `CreatureSpawnEvent`, or another spawn event like that, make sure that:

```
!event.getSpawnReason().equals(SpawnReason.CUSTOM)
```

Before spawning the entity again, to avoid an infinite loop

Although there should be almost no delay between spawning and customizing the entities, if wanted, you could spawn them in a separate location (like a spawn world or something), and then teleport both them to the correct location before setting the passenger:

```
horse.teleport(realLocation);
skeleton.teleport(realLocation);

horse.setPassenger(skeleton);
```

This should not be necessary, though, unless you are doing customization asynchronously, which shouldn't be done with setting information of entities in the first place.

Comment: I don't really understand that. When is it spawned? Aren't you just saving a non existing entity to a local variable and then editing it? I feel like something is missing there. Something like `Bukkit.getLocation().getWorld().spawn(loc, horse)`

Comment: @Myst No, it's spawning it and then saving it to a local variable.

Comment: It doesn't work, it crashes my server. I got 85,000 lines of this http://pastebin.com/nrBauKqG it errors on the line `Horse horse = (Horse) location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.HORSE);`

Comment: @Myst This happens because you have scheduled that line of code to be executed under `CreatureSpawnEvent`. It will throw another event of the same type, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @Myst Joiner is right... Use the code above only when you're spawning an entity... If you can't, check if the entity spawnReason is not CUSTOM first

Comment: @Myst Yes, that should work. I'm updating the answer now

Comment: It currently does not, and I have no idea why. It still crashes

Comment: Update: It works! I have a long list of various custom mobs and one was casted to the wrong type which was the error, and I didn't see it because notepad++ does not update a file if you open it when you already have it open, which happened on the log file. Fixed that and it worked. Thanks all.